# HTTPS connection in iphone

Tags: iphone, ssl, https

How to connect to https url from iphone application ? 
Is there any sample code available?

Answer (score 1):

The same way that you connect to a http URL. The Cocoa Touch API does all the hard stuff behind the scenes.

"Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=306" means "[A connection could not be established to the specified HTTP proxy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors/kcferrorhttpproxyconnectionfailure?language=objc)." Seems that there's a problem with your networking configuration.

Comment: Hello Stephen,
Thanks for reply.
When I connect to http url using NSURLConnection, it is working fine.
What changes I need to do to connect to https url ?
When I change the url to https & keep code same as http I am getting error as :Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=306 UserInfo=0x17ae40 "Operation could not be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 306.)".
Please help. What else I need to implement ?

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and add that information?

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead

Comment: @hnh Super-easy to search for the replacement link on the Apple Developer website though.

Comment: Yes, sure. But that wasn't the point ;-) Thanks for updating!

Comment: It is a closed question from 2009...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use anything special in order to GET information through HTTPS protocol in iOS.

1. If you need to display HTML information, use [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview)
2. If you just need to POST or GET something, use [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl) in combination with NSData, NSString or something to retrieve the information contained in it.

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereIs der any way to estabilish a secure connection with the server using tcp with sslv3. I need some sample code and the way to implement. now I am just setting the readstream and writestream's property as follows

```
[readStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3];

[writeStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3];
```

do any one provide some sample link or sample code in order to estabilish a secure connection using tcp with sslv3

Regards,
Mohammed Sadiq.